# JQL: How do I search for JIRA issues that link to URLs with a certain pattern?

Tags: jira, jql

In Jira, we use regular Web Links to point to an independent issue tracking system (for customer support). Those links can easily be identified by their domain name or URL prefix, e.g., they all have this form:

```
http://support.mycompany.com/ticket#1234
```

How can I filter for Jira issues that have links to URLs following this pattern?

The JQL editor does not offer anything related to issue links, and "link" and "URL" are genuinely bad search terms.

Answer (score 1):

[ScriptRunner for JIRA](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/com.onresolve.jira.groovy.groovyrunner) offers the Script JQL function ["linkedIssuesOfRemote"](https://jamieechlin.atlassian.net/wiki/display/GRV/Scripted+JQL+Functions+With+Comments) that searches for issues that have a link to a specific web page, e.g.:

```
issuefunction in linkedIssuesOfRemote("http://support.mycompany.com/ticket#1234")
```

will return all issues that link to that page. Instead of the link you might use the link title too.

Unfortunately wildcards are not (yet) supported, thus this doesn't work:

```
issuefunction in linkedIssuesOfRemote("http://support.mycompany.com/ticket*")
```

Answer (score 1):

[JavaRunner for JIRA 6.28](https://docs.adaptavist.com/sr4js/6.28.0/features/jql-functions/included-jql-functions/issue-links) Does have support for wild card characters so you should be able to support what you need with.

issuefunction in linkedIssuesOfRemote("http://support.mycompany.com/ticket*")